# How do i convert $\frac{1}{2+x}$ to a summation?

Tags: power-series

I am given the summation for $\frac{1}{1-x}$. I get that I need to sub in $-x$ for $x$. I don't get how  I am supposed to know where I put the $2$.

I am not sure if there is a systematic procedure or if I am just lacking analytical skill.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Factor out the 2 from the denominator, to get $\frac{1}{2(1-(-(x/2)})$ and treat it as the sum of a geometric progression.

Comment: Does that mean I have 1/2 as a coefficient of sigma, and i have negative half x where x should be?

Comment: :please see my answer below and let me know if you have a question.

Comment: Let x = -1-u.  Then 1/(2+x) = 1/(2-1-u) = 1/(1-u).  Don't worry about your analytic skill -- it will grow.

Comment: @yanbo if you're going to edit the question, make sure you read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $${1\over (2+x)}={1\over 2(1-({-x\over 2}))}.$$ This is now in the form of the geometric series. So $${1\over 2}\cdot {1\over (1-({-x\over 2})}={1\over 2}\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty ({-x\over 2})^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n\over 2^{n+1}}x^n.$$

Comment: Is there a reason why x^n is written out of the fraction? Also, why did you separate (-1)^n ?

Comment: No reason really, just something I always do. I keep constants on the left. I did separate it. We had $(-x)^n=(-1)^nx^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that for $|r|$<1 , we have:

$$ \frac{1}{1-r}=1-r+r^2+......$$

Rewrite $\frac{1}{2+x}$ as $\frac{1}{2(1+x/2)}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-(-x/2)}$, and

apply the above identity.

Comment: Several of the $-$ signs should be $+$ (except for the left-hand-side of the above identity with $r$s).

Comment: You're right, let me rewrite.